# Python 2.7 on Openshift V3: update setuptools before build?

Tags: python, kubernetes, openshift

When installing `cryptography` package I get the following error:

```
Invalid environment marker: platform_python_implementation != 'PyPy'
```

It seems upgrading setuptools would solve this. Is there a way I could edit Build Config YAML file so that `pip install --upgrade setuptools` runs before any package is built?

Answer (score 5):

Run:

```
oc set env bc/yourappname UPGRADE_PIP_TO_LATEST=true
```

See:

- https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-python-container/tree/master/2.7

When you do this it should update `pip`, `setuptools` and `wheel` packages.

Only problem is that right at this minute, the changes that were made such that `setuptools` and `wheel` were also updated aren't yet in RHEL based Python S2I images. So if you are using OpenShift Container Platform (as used by OpenShift Online), it will not work as required.

First option to workaround that is to use the CentOS based images instead for now:

```
oc new-app centos/python-27-centos7~https://url-to-your-repo
```

Second option is to add an executable shell script called `.s2i/bin/assemble` in your source code repo which contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eo pipefail

pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

/usr/libexec/s2i/assemble
```

This will be executed instead of the normal `assemble` script, allowing you to install the updates. You then run the original `assemble` script.

Comment: Went with second option. Worked like a charm. Thanks.