# openshift starter project - failed to pull builder image

Tags: openshift

I am running a small system on Openshift Starter - US-West Oregon region.  This was working fine for the last several months until it suddenly started failing yesterday and today.  When I try to rebuild from within the Openshift Web Console, I get this error message in the console:  `Failed to pull builder image.`

In the logs, I get:

`Pulling image "registry.access.redhat.com/rhscl/python-27-rhel7@xxx" ...
pulling image error : pulling image "registry.access.redhat.com/rhscl/python-27-rhel7@xxx" timed out after 2m0s
error: build error: unable to get registry.access.redhat.com/rhscl/python-27-rhel7@xxx`

Since the bit after "rhel7@" seems to be a hash of some kind, and I assume that may have security implications, I have replaced it with "xxx" in this post.

Some months ago our system went down and it turned out to be a problem with the Openshift servers (see [the discussion in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652294/what-does-openshift-mean-when-it-says-its-evicted-my-pods-and-why-does-it-k)).  As there's been no significant changes from our end to the code in months, I assume this problem is also on Openshift's end.  However, the [status blog](https://status.starter.openshift.com/) does not say anything about problems in this server.

Is it likely to be an Openshift problem, or should I look more closely at what is going on in our software?

**EDIT:** Today, April 30th, I received an email from Openshift saying that we should "Create an application by 09:00pm on May 4, 2018 (EDT, GMT -04:00)" or the account will be deactivated.  But there's already an application that was running!  Does anyone know what is going on? I've also filed a request with the "community support" system on the site.

Comment: Is this ``us-west-1`` or ``us-west-2``?

Comment: It's the us-west-2 region

Comment: Can you try doing a rebuild again. There was an issue with certificates which may have been causing the issue. I believe that may now be fixed, or at least is in process of being fixed.

Comment: As to accounts being deactivated, as the platform is for experimentation only, it expects that you are periodically interacting with it, doing new builds and deployments etc. If you just deploy something and leave it for a long time and don't do anything, it will be deactivated. In other words, it isn't meant to be used for permanent production sites. If you have been working with it and still got that, then not sure why you would get the notification.

Comment: On your second issue about receiving a notification email, you will get it if you have no project or don't have any pods running in your project for a few days. Once you deploy an application and so create at least one pod, your project/account is no longer queued to be deactivated, but be aware that there is no notification sent to update that the status has changed. If you have pods currently running, provide your project name so that the issue can be investigated.

Comment: That did it, thank you. It's working now.  Re the notification, I have been periodically interacting with the system with minor changes etc, but there had been a gap. However it seems like the reason was more likely the fact that nothing was running, as a result of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to have been in the certificates in Openshift, as commented by Graham Dumpleton above.  It's working now.  Leaving this question and answer here for reference in case this happens to someone else in future.